# SSH Config: How to Stop Repeating a Setting/Have it in the Wildcard Host?

Tags: docker, ssh-config

I have a repeating setting `remoteCommand`, that I'd like to add in the wild card host if possible.

Here is a truncated snippet:

```bash
host container-server

host container-1 
  remoteCommand docker exec -it containerHostname-01 bash

host container-2
  remoteCommand docker exec -it containerHostname-02 bash

host container-2
  remoteCommand docker exec -it containerHostname-02 bash

host * 
  user <user>
  requestTTY yes
  identityFile ~/.ssh/key
  strictHostkeyChecking no
  userKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  preferredAuthentications publicKey
  hostname <hostname of container server>
```

As `containerHostname-0<int>` all differ by an integer, I'm assuming it can't be done, and I've researched for days and came back with nothing, so is it possible?

Comment: You can create a script to generate ssh's config

Comment: Any details? Perhaps in an answer? Not sure how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the `ssh` config don't allow the use of variables nor loops.

So AFAIK, you can't use a wildcard to generate different commands for different numbered hosts.

Instead, you can generate a config file, using the shell, here, `bash` chosen:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    printf '%s\n' "host container-${i}\n\tremoteCommand docker exec -it containerHostname-${i} bash" >> file
done
```

Comment: thanks, suppose this is the next best thing but now I know for sure I can't do what I was trying.